# Defend against T-SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, code-injection

Apologies if this seems a daft question but how does using parameters defends against SQL injection and what are the best practices in relation to T-SQL:

For example: Is this best practice?

```
SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SQL Command @X ....... @Y");
SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@X", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = X;
SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Y", SqlDbType.date).Value = Y;
SqlCmd.Connection = ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Thanks but I am also interested in general best practices and as the comments mention what about overflow. Etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use SQL Parameters. Using the SqlParameterCollection (as in your example: `SqlCmd.Parameters`) automatically provides you with:

1. Type checking
2. Length validation
3. Input is treated as a literal value rather than as executable code
4. Handling of special characters normally involved in SQL injection attacks

[There are some additional best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx), including:

- Constrain and sanitize input data
- Use an account that has restricted permissions in the database
- Avoid disclosing database error information

You'll find those best practices further described at this [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Thank you the last link is particularly useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this code is safe from SQL injection.

The reason is that when working with parameters your passing the items as a value to your server and they will be interpreted as such.

If you would construct a string, SQL cannot know what the value is and what the query is and has to rely purely on syntax.